# C# Multiplication Table - Only 1 multiplication is showing

Tags: c#

I am creating a multiplication table, when you input a number and click the calculate button it should display. I have tried watching a few tutorials on YouTube and have checked out some coding forums however I can only find people using the Console Application however I am using the Windows Form Application

```
1 * 1 = 1 
2 * 1 = 2 
3 * 1 = 3
4 * 1 = 4
5 * 1 = 5
6 * 1 = 6
7 * 1 = 7
8 * 1 = 8
9 * 1 = 9
10 * 1 = 10
```

However, when I run the program it only displays

```
1 * 10 = 10
```

Here is my code;

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n, i;
    n = Int32.Parse(txtNum.Text);
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        txtCalc.Text = Convert.ToString(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i);
}
```

Comment: Run your code [in the debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and look at `txtCalc.Text` each iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Three answers in a minute! You are very fortunate :)

Comment: @Felix I'd like to think it's because OP provided enough detail to provide meaningful answers. Something we see far too infrequently.

Comment: @DourHighArch I have ran my code in the debugger however, this isn't giving me any means to fix the issue as I am getting no feedback from debugging. The issue has now been resolved however by another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the text over and over again. What you want to do is append new text every time through the loop. Try something like:

```
txtCalc.Text = "";

for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    txtCalc.Text += Convert.ToString(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I can now see where I went wrong. I am unable to accept this answer yet but will do so once I able to

Answer (score 2):

This loop keeps setting the control's text to a different value over and over, leaving you to see only the final value.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    txtCalc.Text = Convert.ToString(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i);
}
```

A straightforward solution is:

```
string text = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    text += Convert.ToString(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i);
}
txtCalc.Text = text;
```

You will still run into some formatting issues you'll need to solve, but you'll get the fundamental info in there.

Answer (score 1):

your `txtCalc.Text...` overwrites the field in every iteration. You probably want something like this:

```
txtCalc.Text = "";
for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    txtCalc.Text += Convert.ToString(n + " * " + i + " = " + n * i);
}
```